# AWS Key Pair Replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm, key-pair

I am looking to replace my lost AWS Key Pair.
I have searched near and far, youtube clips, resources articles on AWS, and others. Yet I am nowhere near where I need to be.

Please can someone steer me in the proper direction?
I would appreciate your assistance as I have an instance already running.

Comment: If the EC2 instance was correctly configured, you may be able to use a [Systems Manager Session](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#start-sys-console) to connect. And there's an additional, somewhat older option: [Connect to your Linux instance if you lose your private key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html).

Answer (score 2):

To replace a lost key pair, you can use the AWS Systems Manager AWSSupport-ResetAccess Automation document. Or, you can create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the existing instance, launch a new instance, and then select a new key pair.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-replace-lost-key-pair/

Hoe to use AWSSupport-ResetAccess

This runbook will use the EC2Rescue tool on the specified EC2 instance to re-enable password decryption using the EC2 Console (Windows) or to generate and add a new SSH key pair (Linux). If you lost your key pair, this automation will create a password-enabled AMI that you can use to launch a new EC2 instance with a key pair you own (Windows).

Go through link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-resetaccess.html

Comment: Thank to Deepak - I will go through the documentation and revert with solution when solved.